# Texture being stretched when using D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP

Tags: textures, directx, directx9, skybox

I'm trying to create a skybox using a cube and using one of this textures: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/mundus-skybox-pack-01-released.202748/

I've got it working well, but I noticed there are some bugs on the edges of the cube, as it can be seen here: 
[image]

I found that this could be fixed using clamping, so I set `D3DSAMP_ADDRESSU` and `D3DSAMP_ADDRESSV` to `D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP`. This, however, produced the following result:
[image]

Half of the cube wasn't being shown and the other half was only showing a one-pixel wide texture region.
I saw [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772711/directx-texture-rendered-incorretly) (which uses wrapping though), but I'm already using 4 vertices per face.
So, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the texture coordinates that you're using for those vertices? With `D3DTADDRESS_CLAMP`, they must be in the [0;1] range, anything else will be clamped to [0;1]. So, for example, using the [-1;0] coordinate range could cause this as it would make all of them effectively 0.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it (I forgot I was flipping the V coordinate xD). But to remove the seams completely, I had to extend all squares some more pixels, so the UVs didn't touch the border directly.